# EF Core (LINQ) - The Query expression could not be Translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following query for searching records by parameter.

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
var pastDueInvoices =  Context.Invoice.AsNoTracking()
                .Select(i => new InvoiceDTO
                {
                    ID = i.ID,
                    InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
                    DaysPastDue =  i.Balance <= 0 ? 0 : CurrentDate.Subtract(i.InvoiceDate.AddDays(i.ProductNav.DiscountDays.GetValueOrDefault())).Days,
                });
```

Then I used this query to display only invoices where DaysPastDue > 0

```
 if (request.ShowPastDueInvoices)
{                    
  pastDueInvoices =  pastDueInvoices.Where(pd => pd.DaysPastDue > 0);
}
```

when i search for past due invoices I get the following error

> .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: i =>
> EF.Property<Nullable>(i, "ProductID"), outerKeySelector: p =>
> EF.Property<Nullable>(p, "ID"), innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new
> TransparentIdentifier<Invoice, Product>( Outer = o, Inner = i ))
> .Where(i =>
> __CurrentDate_0.Subtract(i.Outer.InvoiceDate.AddDays((double)i.Inner.DiscountDays.GetValueOrDefault())).Days > 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
> inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
> ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Any Help?

Comment: Your codes have to sport SQL queries. So you shouldn't use things like Subtract.
Try to write code for in select by using Ef.Functions.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage I am using Sql server, NET core 3.1.0

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x?

Comment: @NetMage Oh sorry Linq to EF 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely EF Core cannot translate the `Subtract` method to SQL. Accoring to [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/1145ef9b3dd46a07a84cb04b11141ecc8bfc62d2/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/SqlServerDateAddTranslator.cs) EF core has a `DateTime.AddDays` provider built in but I was unable to find such a provider for `Substract` or `DateDiff` in the official documentation. So, you can try using EF.Functions which gives you access to [DbFunctions class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-6.0) with helper methods for SQL operations `EF.Functions.DateDiffDay` i.e.

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
var pastDueInvoices =  Context.Invoice.AsNoTracking()
            .Select(i => new InvoiceDTO
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
                DaysPastDue =  i.Balance <= 0 ? 0 : EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(CurrentDate, i.InvoiceDate.AddDays(i.ProductNav.DiscountDays.GetValueOrDefault())),
            });
```

I'm not sure about this `GetValueOrDefault()` method if it will be translated to SQL. If it is some custom extension method written by you most likely not. Maybe you should try to replace it with something like `i.ProductNav.DiscountDays ?? 0` or maybe you don't need to manually convert `nullable` days column value to `0`, there is a good chance that SQL server will directly translate a null column value to 0 for use in `DATEADD`SQL function. Try both cases.

Also, the original EF 6 (not core) version of this will use [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
var pastDueInvoices =  Context.Invoice.AsNoTracking()
        .Select(i => new InvoiceDTO
        {
            ID = i.ID,
            InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
            DaysPastDue =  i.Balance <= 0 ? 0 : DbFunctions.DiffDays(CurrentDate, DbFunctions.AddDays(i.InvoiceDate, i.ProductNav.DiscountDays)),
        })
```